# How to get width of absolute positioned element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to get the width off a component but it is 0. I've also tried putting the code in ngOnChanges().

```
constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
  this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
  let width = this.htmlElement.offsetWidth;
}
```

Element style:

```
display: block;
position: absolute;
left: 100;
```

I tried using clientWidth() but it is 0 too. How can I get the width of an element in angular 2?

**Update:**

I don't use position absolute and the width is correct, so I suppose the question is how do I get the width of an absolute positioned element?

Comment: add your HTML code ?

Comment: its just a div with display block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your code to `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook method and use [@ViewChild()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator instead of injecting element directly in `constructor`.

Try this code:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, HTMLElement, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div #child>
      <h2>Hello!</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('child') element: any;
  htmlElement: HTMLElement;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
    let width = this.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
  }
}
```

Or see [the working example here](https://plnkr.co/edit/0GIA0r0w5e7TP2DBhd1n). Also check comments for explanations.

Comment: same result still 0

Comment: It appears the problem is in the way you get a reference to the element. When you inject element in `constructor` it's not rendered yet in DOM and since you don't do any manual change detections it stays `0` which is a default value. Try to reference your element with [@ViewChild()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) decorator instead. See [the working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0GIA0r0w5e7TP2DBhd1n) and let me know if it helped so I can update my answer.

Comment: Please see the demo I shared in the previous comment. It gives the correct value for an `absolute` positioned element.

Comment: It's weird because I do see correct width in console.log. Please note this will give you only initial width after an element has been rendered. It *will not* update value dynamically when you change the content of an element.

Comment: its working and I didn't need to create a child element, just needed ngAfterViewInit()

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
const rect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const width = rect.width;
```

Comment: still 0 for the width

Answer (score 0):

You should associate it to the element to the elementRef

```
@ViewChild('foo') foo: TemplateRef;

<div #foo>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
    {{foo.clientWidth}}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/1w96WHDQ0HgEklEFNdEg?p=preview)**